# iPhone Zoom Transition between 2 UIViews

Tags: iphone, uiview, zooming, transition

I have a small floating UIView, viewHover, which acts as a container to 2 views "viewHot and viewCold"

I which to transition between viewHot and viewCold with a zoom in then disolve transition I have seen a few times.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible because that transition does not exist

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone else...

//hotViewController.m

```
  hotViewController *hotController = [[[hotViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 

  [hotController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; 

  [self presentModalViewController:hotController animated:YES];
```

//coldViewController.m

```
  -(IBAction)back:(id)sender {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  }
```